# How to prevent 'Overscroll history navigation' without preventing touchstart?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, touch, preventdefault

I'm implementing a swipe-base navigation, and I'm running into trouble with Chrome.

A newly implemented feature, 'Overscroll history navigation', is triggered when the page is dragged to the right, causing a jump back (to 'history -1'). To prevent this, I'd have to call `.preventDefault()` on `touchstart`, but this also disables everything from clicking links to scrolling.
How do I prevent browser UI events without interfering with the standard page?

Disabling the feature altogether by setting the appropriate flag in chrome fixes the issue, but isn't practical for a public-facing application.
chrome://flags/#overscroll-history-navigation

Comment: Did you ever figure out this problem. I've been googling all day and can't get anywhere.

Comment: Yes, I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I eventually figured out a solution:

Chrome fires at least `touchstart` and `touchmove` before overscrolling. By tracking the direction of those events, an overscroll can be filtered from regular scrolling.

I've written up the code [for this Hammer.js issue](https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/issues/494#issuecomment-42651000).

Answer (score 0):

To leave scrolling vertical working and moving elemets horizontally you need to check if moving is more along x then y axis by comparing coordinates differences using Math.abs(), then decide to call .preventDefault() in touchmove event or not.

Sounds little strange but i think it is the only way to control this behemoth feature "Overscroll history navigation". ble.

```
$(function () {

    function extract(e) {
        if (e.changedTouches) {
            e = e.changedTouches;
            if (e['0'])
                e = e['0'];
        }
        return e;
    }

    var div = $('div').html('Drag me left and right and see that Overscroll is disabled & drag me up and down to see that scroll still works<br /><br /><br />'.repeat(300));
    var di  = div.get(0); // get native dom element

    var startx, lastx, lasty, l = false, active = false;

    di.addEventListener("touchstart", function (e) {
        active = true;
        e = extract(e);

        // init
        lastx = e.pageX;
        lasty = e.pageY;

        l = parseInt(div.css('left'), 10);
        startx = e.pageX;
    }, false);

    di.addEventListener("touchmove", function (ee) {
        if (active) {
            var e = extract(ee);

            // check if preventDefault to cancel Overscroll history navigation only if it's needed
            if (Math.abs(lastx - e.pageX) > Math.abs(lasty - e.pageY)) {
                ee.preventDefault();
            }

            // update x y to next above calculation
            lastx = e.pageX;
            lasty = e.pageY;

            // repositioning
            div.css({left: (l + (e.pageX - startx))+'px'})
        }
    }, false);

    di.addEventListener("touchend", function (e) {
        active = false;
    }, false);
});
```

Complete example to test on touch devices: [DEMO](http://codepen.io/stopsopa/full/rOoRbM/)

Answer (score 0):

- listen to `onscroll` event on the container and store the 'scrollLeft' value
  `this.offsetX = event.currentTarget.scrollLeft;`
- listen to `onwheel` event on the same container and use this handler

```js
var offset = 0;

document.getElementById("1")
  .addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {
     offset = event.currentTarget.scrollLeft;
  });
document.getElementById("1")
  .addEventListener("wheel", function(event) {
    // if we reach the left side of the scrollable content, and we scroll further -> block the event

    if (offset === 0 && event.deltaX <= 0) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow: auto;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.element {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="1" class="container">
  <div class="element">
  1
  </div>
  <div class="element">
  2
  </div>
  <div class="element">
  3
  </div>
  <div class="element">
  4
  </div>
  <div class="element">
  5
  </div>
  <div class="element">
  6
  </div>
  <div class="element">
  7
  </div>
  <div class="element">
  8
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overscroll-behavior: contain;    
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overscroll-behavior

Comment: This did not work for me sadly. I tried setting it on body and on the scrollable element (a horizontally scrollable list) with contain and none. But it kept navigating. Interestingly it did it way before i overscrolled (reached the beginning of the list) when i made a quick gesture. there seems to be more than just overscrolling causing this in Chrome.

Comment: yea doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

It's 'touchmove' you will have to stopPropagation() AND preventDefault() inside the callback you can call whatever you need for checking the swipe and your navigation to happen.