# How to disable overscroll history navigation via javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ngdraggable

I'm using ngdraggable on my webproject. With mouse drag and drop everything works as expected but when I use touch gestures in chrome I always use overscroll history navigation.

I already know how to disable it in the browser but I need to know how to disable it via javascript.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent 'Overscroll history navigation' without preventing touchstart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23560528/how-to-prevent-overscroll-history-navigation-without-preventing-touchstart)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overscroll Navigation Flag not working on Chome command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55143891/overscroll-navigation-flag-not-working-on-chome-command-line)