# Overscroll Navigation Flag not working on Chome command line

Tags: google-chrome

I am trying to execute chrome as

```
chrome.exe --overscroll-history-navigation=0 --disable-pinch
```

with the --disable-pinch --overscroll-history-navigation=0 flags in command line but it does not work at all.

I am using Chrome Versión 73.0.3683.75. It does not forbid the overscroll gestures.... I am about to go crazy....:|, it worked perfectly but stopped working at some point last week.

Any help is sooo welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have also been battling this one but have finally found the solution that works for me. It seems that since a couple of chrome versions back the *overscroll-history-navigation* flag has been removed from the command line options. However, you can still access it from the chrome flags page by visiting this url in chrome:

```
    chrome://flags/#overscroll-history-navigation
```

and manually disable it there.

Unfortunately this didn't solve it for me as I am also running the --kiosk mode switch for a touchscreen kiosk application developed in HTML and I cant expect every user to go to the flags page to disable this.

What did work was to add the css *overscroll-behavior* tag to both the html and body tags in the css for the application:

```
    html,body {overscroll-behavior: none;}
```

Problem solved! No annoying swiping navigation on chrome. Not sure why if the --kiosk switch is enabled this sort of behaviour isn't automatically switched off?

Anyhow, hope this helps you too.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! It really was breaking my nerves... I will try it ASAP, thats on Monday, and will let you know if it works. Thanks again!

Comment: @ÁngelBlanco did you get to try it? As far as I can see these flags have now been removed (as of Feb 2021).

Comment: Thanks! I confirm both are needed on `html` and `body`.